# An order such that $1 \leq 0$

Tags: relations, order-theory

I want to know if this makes sense:

Consider the set $\{0,1\}$ with the total order relation: $x \leq y$ if $x^y = 1$. It is reflexive, since $1^1 = 1$ and $0^0 = 1$ (I'm adopting this definition). It is vacuously antissymetric and it is transitive: $1 \leq 0, 0 \leq 0$ and $ 1 \leq 1$ are all the pairings. I'm not sure if what I'm making is OK, something feels odd to me. Please verify my possible mistakes.

Comment: It seems you're right. However, if want an order such that $1\leq 0$, why don't you consider the inverse of the usual $\leq$? You can define $x\succeq y$ if and only if $y\leq x$. It works for all real numbers.

Comment: the only thing that feels odd to me is $0^0=1$. If you want a more natural definition of this order try $x\leq y$ when $x$ divides $y$.

Comment: Something can feel odd while still being correct. (This is definitely an example of that.)

Comment: This is correct. The only thing that I find "odd" is defining something as simple as the reverse of the usual order by using something as complicated (in general) as exponentiation.

Comment: Why don't you just define $\le $ as for any $x,y $ we have $x\le y $.  It doesn't have trichotomy however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As observed in the comments by @Dog_69, @Eran, @MiloBrandt, @AndreasBlass and @fleablood, it's correct, although there are more simple ways to do it, for example $x \leq' y \iff x \geq y$ or $x \leq' y \iff x | y$.